# How would I replace all '?' in the phrase with a random letter but the letter used cannot repeat twice in a row?

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, replace

For example say you have the string 'ab?d?f' and you must grab the string and replace it with any random letters in the '?' like 'abcdef' or 'abjdlf' but it cannot be 'abbdef' or 'abcdff'.

I have attempted this below:

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

const randomLeter = () => letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)];

const riddle = 'ab?d?f';

let pickedLetter;
let solvedRiddle;

function solve(riddle) {
    for (let i = 0; i < riddle.length; i++) {
        if (riddle[i] === '?' && !(riddle[i-1] === randomLeter) && !(riddle[i+1] === randomLeter)){
            console.log('Changing to letter');
            solvedRiddle = riddle.replace('?', pickedLetter);
        }
        pickedLetter = randomLeter();
        console.log(i, riddle[i], pickedLetter);
    }
    return solvedRiddle;
}
// The above only returns the first '?' changed but leaves the second one unchanged ... ??? Why can I not change the value of solvedRiddle a second time inside the loop? I can see by my log that it reads at true, but the value won't be re-written.
console.log(solve(riddle));
```

Comment: `randomLeter` is a function, which means you need to use `randomLeter()` in your code to actually call it. Otherwise you're comparing the riddle letter to the function, not its returned value.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that mistake! Adding the () still leaves me with the same issue unfortunately though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function solve(riddle) {
    for (let i = 0; i < riddle.length; i++) {
        if (riddle[i] === '?'){
            console.log('Changing to letter');
            let pickedLetter = randomLeter();
            while (riddle[i-1] === pickedLetter || riddle[i+1] === pickedLetter) {
              pickedLetter = randomLeter();
            }
            riddle = riddle.replace('?', pickedLetter);
        }
    }
    return riddle;
}
```

Also, it's because u update and return `solvedRiddle`. Your original `riddle` string is not updated, so in the second run, it is still changing the first `?`

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code so that it suits the needs, however there may be some bugs or exceptions not handled yet, but it can give you a hint that how you are going to solve the problem.

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

let randomLeter = (excluded) =>
{
   let letter = false;
   do
   {
       letter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)];
   }
   while(excluded.includes(letter));
   
   return letter;
}

let getIndices = (s, t) => {
  return [...s].flatMap((char, i) => (char === t ? i : []));
};

let Solve = (riddle) => 
{
    riddle = [...riddle];
    //get the locations of all ? in the string
    let all = getIndices(riddle, '?'); 
    
    for(let i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
    {
        //exluding characters before and after the ?
        let excluded = [riddle[all[i] - 1], riddle[all[i] + 1]];

        riddle[all[i]] = randomLeter(excluded);
    }
    
    return riddle.join("");
};

let riddle = 'ab?d?f';
document.getElementById('riddle').innerHTML = 'The Riddle ' + riddle;
document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML = "Solution " + Solve(riddle);
```

```html
<h2 id="riddle"></h2>
<h4 id="solution"></h4>
```

Comment: This also works well to what I was looking for. Thanks for this method another take on it I would've never guessed.